# How to create a new characters and use them within python?

Tags: python, module, special-characters

I want to be able to make my own character set, like ascii, maybe only 10 characters or so. I know I can make my own characters using the windows private character editor, but I need a way to call these characters, like chr() and ord().

For example:

```
print(new_chars(1))
>>> <New Character Number One>
print(new_chars(10))
>>> <New Character Number Ten>
```

If I can do this, I'd probably just turn it into my own module.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you please explain what you want, do you want a define that will do that for you or something else, expand your question please.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a function with a list of your own characters and than just simply call the function with demanded index

Comment: Oh yes, then I could turn that into a module that I could call, thankyou.